# Tableau: Create a parameter to see individual fields or sum

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

I have 3 variables of interest:

- City
- Amount
- Round: can take value of A or B

My dashboard is set such as each row represents a city, an in the column there is the amount.
The amount column is divided in 2: Round A and Round B. (the user can see the amount for each round next to each other).

I am trying to create a filter or parameter that let's me see the Amount for round A and B next to each other or the sum of both. Currently, the filter allows me to see round A or round B or both next to each other. I want to also be able to see the sum.

I was advised to make a parameter this way (it does change anything):

1. Right click on Round measure and create parameter. I added values from Round.
2. Show Parameter
3. Right Click on Round measure and create set. On the condition tab, by formula: [Round] = [Round Parameter]

Thanks (absolute beginner on Tableau)

[image]

Comment: So Your round A is jan 2020 to Nov 2020 and round B is upto Dec 2019+Dec2020?  Am I Correct?  Have you tried sub-totals from Analysis menu?  Can you please include a screenshot of your dashboard or alternatively your book on tableau public and share a link, please?

Comment: @AnilGoyal     We can forget about how I derived the Round variable, it's actually irrelevant to my problem. I posted a picture of how my table looks like. I would just like a filter that let's me see just round A, just round B, Round A and Round B (like in the picture) and the SUM of round A + Round B. I now also mentioned what I tried doing. Thanks!

Comment: So I was asking about `round` field because the question was not clear earlier.  See the answer, if I have correctly understood it now!

Comment: @AnilGoyal thanks a lot! there seem to be an issue with the sum part (even in your GIF). I suspect it comes from the Rounds calculated field, the last line.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.  The error was in `AMTS` field.  Now corrected, please check

Comment: Works perfectly! You've been very helpful, I'll use this way for other similar tasks I have as well. thanks!

Comment: Glad to have been help.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this (see the GIF)

[image]

Proceed like this-

sample data taken

[image]

**Step-1** create a parameter (say `parameter 1`) like this

[image]

**Step-2** create two calculation fields with the following calculations-

`ROUNDS` with the following calculation

```
CASE [Parameter 1]
when 3 THEN [Round]
when 1 THEN (IF  [Round] = 'A' THEN [Round] end)
when 2 THEN (IF  [Round] = 'B' THEN [Round] end)
when 4 THEN 'Total'
END
```

**Step-3** another calc field say `AMTS` as

```
CASE [Parameter 1]
when 3 THEN [Amt]
when 1 THEN (IF  [Round] = 'A' THEN [Amt] end)
when 2 THEN (IF  [Round] = 'B' THEN [Amt] end)
when 4 THEN [Amt]
END
```

**STEP-4** Build the view using `ROUNDS` instead of `round` and `AMTS` instead of `Amt`, show parameter, click on NULL field when shown and `EXCLUDE` it. and you are done.

[image]